# Can I connect DC GND to AC earth? If so, what is the purpose?

Tags: ac, dc, grounding, earth

I am trying to use the circuit shown below in the picture.

In the circuit, from the AC supply, the PE is connected with the ground symbol. I assumed I need to connect PE (protective earth) with the DC Gnd (-ve terminal).

Is that correct?

[image: AC charging]

Comment: The term "PE" actually means protective earth and not potential earth.

Comment: It is of course possible, but also quite possible to let the magic smoke escape.
Please be more elaborative on the situation: What DC, a battery? What PE, from mains? If the DC is from a not-well-isolated power supply, it could well be making a mains circuit, and PE is commonly neutral with an RCD in between, so that might trip if the current exceeds the limit, or just destroy the DC device by exposing it to mains voltages

Comment: Sorry for the vague question description before. I have updated the question with the schematic. I hope it will be detailed.

Comment: There's nothing in that picture that helps especially when safety is concerned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of linking a DC device to an earth is often to leak static electricity away from the device. This could be generated by a rotating part, like a fan or a harddisk for example, or a lot of other causes, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_electricity)